# Need to get line number in text file matching string

Tags: php

I need to get the line number of a text file using PHP. The line I need is "WANT THIS LINE".

I tried using file() to put the file lines in an array and search using array_search() but it won't return the line number. In this example I would need to return 3 as the line number.

```
$file = file("file.txt");
$key = array_search("WANT", $file);
echo $key;
```

Text File:

```
First Line of Code
Some Other Line
WANT THIS LINE
Last Line
```

Comment: That isn't how `array_search` works. You'll need `array_search("WANT THIS LINE", $file);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

array_search() is looking for an exact match. You'll need to loop through the array entries looking for a partial match

```
$key = 'WANT';
$found = false;
foreach ($file as $lineNumber => $line) {
    if (strpos($line,$key) !== false) {
       $found = true;
       $lineNumber++;
       break;
    }
}
if ($found) {
   echo "Found at line $lineNumber";
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'm getting: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). I put a value for $file at first line

Comment: Are you reading the file correctly into $file? Test for $file !== false befor ethe loop... if it is false, then it hasn't read correctly

Comment: ahh yeah forgot to put back in $file = file(). Also needed to change $line to echo "Found at line $lineNumber"; THANKS AGAIN!

Answer (score 3):

This should be more memory efficient than loading the file into an array

```
foreach (new SplFileObject('filename.txt') as $lineNumber => $lineContent) {
    if(trim($lineContent) === 'WANT THIS LINE') {
        echo $lineNumber; // zero-based
        break;
    }
}
```

If you just want to search for parts of a word, replace

```
if(trim($lineContent) === 'WANT THIS LINE') {
```

with

```
if (FALSE !== strpos($lineContent, 'WANT')) {
```

Comment: Thank you. This is much better than the above solution.