# PHP: Get all lines containing specific text

Tags: php

I'm trying to parse the source code from a website that goes like

```
   <html>
    ...
    ...
    ...
    <div class="menu_body">
    <a href="url" onclick="_gaq.push([parameters]);location.href=this.href+'?channelId=287&date='+dateOfMonth;return false;"> <img src="img"></a>
    <a href="url"><img src="img"></a>
    <a href="url"><img src="img"></a>
    </div>
    ...
    ...
    <div class="menu_body">
    <a href="url"><img src="img></a>
    <a href="url"><img src="img"></a>
    <a href="url"><img src="img"></a>
    </div>
    ...
    ...
    ...
    </html>
```

What I want to do if possible is to just grep out all the lines which contains `channelId`, not sure if it's possible?

Comment: How are you currently parsing this HTML? Could we see your PHP code?

Comment: it would be alot easier to use JavaScript

Comment: and of course you have permission from this site to use their content?

Comment: Currently I'm just saving their source code into a variable using `file_get_contents`. And yes I have permission. Or is there a simpler way for me to grep all the lines which contain `channelId`? Sorta new to php and not sure what functions there are

Comment: By lines, you really mean lines? You really want the whole line, e.g. starting at position 0 ending with a newline character? You dont care about the HTML elements?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need to get line number in text file matching string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926680/need-to-get-line-number-in-text-file-matching-string)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want some sort of HTML Parser

```
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/    <-- PHP
http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/         <--- Java
```

/** @see [Robust and Mature HTML Parser for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php)  */

Answer (score 0):

Read the html as a string using CURL or file_get_contents, and then use
preg_match. 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php