# Searching a text file and displaying a part of the String. (PHP)

Tags: php, html

So I want to search a text file which contains a list of suburbs with names and postcodes. Depending on the the postcode given I want to display the suburb. I know I'm suppose to loop through the text file but have no idea how to actually search for exact value in the line and then display a different part of that same line. I know that I can use the explode function and get the part of the string I want but what I don't know how to do is loop through the file and finding the exact line of it.

Any Help on this is most Appreciated ! 
Thanks !

Comment: You should post an example of the text file and code you have currently tried, along with explanation of where that code is not working as expected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4926680/582278

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't provide any example of what you have tried so far, this may not completely match what you are doing.

Assuming a file `suburbs.txt` with contents like:

```
Somewhere,12345 
Somewhere Else,12346 
This Place,12347 
There,12348
```

You could do the following to loop through the entries:

```
$zipCode = '12346';

$lines = file('/path/to/suburbs.txt');

foreach ( $lines as $line )
{
    $fields = explode( ',', $line );

    if ( $fields[1] == $zipCode )
    {
        echo "Your suburb is: " . $fields[0];
        break;
    }
}
```

`file()` loads a file into an array. This is what allows you to loop through using `foreach()`. There are other methods of doing this as well, but this should help you move in the right direction.

Comment: Hey sorry for the Extremely late reply!. First off thank you very much ! This was way easier to understand. 
Secondly when I asked my tutor about this this is the code he provided. (I'll post it in the next comment since it's too long).